# Change default TextInputLayout style?

Tags: android, material-design, themes, material-components-android, mdc-components

I am using Material Design Components and want to change the default style of a `TextInputLayout`, meaning my changes shall apply to all instances of the `TextInputLayout` without me having to explicitely define a `style="@style/my_style"` on each of them.

If and how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **`textInputStyle`** attribute in your app theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"> 
   <item name="textInputStyle">@style/myCustomStyle</item>
</style>
```